# Ler Serial do arduino com bluetooth 4.0 usando Evothings

Tags: javascript, ios, arduino, bluetooth, serial

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, onde quero que meu iPhone toque informações com o Arduíno a partir do bluetooth 4.0. Consegui me conectar ao bluetooth e também consigo enviar dados pela Serial, porém não estou conseguindo ler os dados da Serial. Usei como base o exemplo do `evothings arduino-ble`, alterei a `linha 166` do arquivo `app.js` como mostrado abaixo:

```
startReading: function(deviceHandle)
{
   console.log('Enabling notifications');

   // Turn notifications on.
   app.write(
      'writeDescriptor',
      deviceHandle,
      app.descriptorNotification,
      new Uint8Array([1,0]));

   // Start reading notifications.
   evothings.ble.enableNotification(
      deviceHandle,
      app.characteristicRead,
      function(data)
      {
         //document.getElementById('dados').innerHTML = data;
         app.drawLines([new DataView(data).getUint8(0, true)]);
      },
      function(errorCode)
      {
         console.log('enableNotification error: ' + errorCode);
      });
},
```

E também mudei os valores da `caracteristic` para os valores específicos do meu bluetooth na `linha 230` do `app.js`

```
getServices: function(deviceHandle)
{
   console.log('Reading services...');

   evothings.ble.readAllServiceData(deviceHandle, function(services)
   {
      // Find handles for characteristics and descriptor needed.
      for (var si in services)
      {
         var service = services[si];

         for (var ci in service.characteristics)
         {
            var characteristic = service.characteristics[ci];
            var resultado="";
                for (propriedade in characteristic) {
                  resultado += propriedade + ": " + characteristic[propriedade] + "\n"; 
                };
                document.getElementById('carac').innerHTML = resultado;

            if (characteristic.uuid == '0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')  // This line changed for HM10
            {   document.getElementById('funcao').innerHTML = "entrei 1 if uuid carac";             
               app.characteristicRead = characteristic.handle;
            }
            else if (characteristic.uuid == '0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')  // This line changed for HM10
            {
                document.getElementById('funcao').innerHTML = "entrei 2 if uuid carac";
               app.characteristicWrite = characteristic.handle;
            }

            for (var di in characteristic.descriptors)
            {
               var descriptor = characteristic.descriptors[di];

               if (characteristic.uuid == '0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb' &&  // This line changed for HM10
                  descriptor.uuid == '00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB')
               {
                  app.descriptorNotification = descriptor.handle;
               }
            }
         }
      }

      if (app.characteristicRead && app.characteristicWrite && app.descriptorNotification)
      {
         console.log('RX/TX services found.');
         app.startReading(deviceHandle);
      }
      else
      {
         console.log('ERROR: RX/TX services not found!');
      }
   },
   function(errorCode)
   {
      console.log('readAllServiceData error: ' + errorCode);
   });
},
```

Porém não funcionou e me retorna `Disconect` no campo "Status" do aplicativo. 
Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Comment: Coloca na pergunta quais são as linhas linha 166 e 230.

Comment: coloquei, a linha 166 é referente a primeira linha do primeiro código colocado na pergunta e a linha 230 é referente a primeira linha do segundo trecho de código disponibilizado na pergunta

Comment: Colocar destacada, não tem como a gente saber qual é a linha só com esse código.